# Spring boot on glassfish 3.x

Tags: spring, glassfish, glassfish-3, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application to Glassfish 3.x but I can't get it to work. If I run the project via `mvn spring-boot:run` or I deploy the war on a Tomcat 7, it works, but if I deploy it on a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 the deploy fails before it even gets to spring boots initialization.

```
[#|2014-08-04T11:38:36.668+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurer|#]

[#|2014-08-04T11:38:36.677+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ org/flywaydb/core/Flyway ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-08-04T11:38:36.700+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while deploying the app [spring]|#]

[#|2014-08-04T11:38:36.700+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=50;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:241)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3217)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3197)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:598)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:456)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:429)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:405)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:380)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:243)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:252)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:213)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:827)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:769)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:145)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:575)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:380)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:220)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Disclaimer: I am using a Controller which extends an `AbstractController`, because we have this structure in another web application, and the next step is to migrate it to Spring Boot.

My configuration so far:

`SampleController.java`

```
@Controller("myController")
public class SampleController extends AbstractController {
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        response.getWriter().print("Hello world!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Application.java`

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping sampleServletMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();

        SampleController sampleController = (SampleController) applicationContext.getBean("myController");
        mapping.setUrlMap(Collections.singletonMap("index", sampleController));
        mapping.setOrder(0);
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hit a limitation in GlassFish 3.x and I don't think it's possible to get this to work.

The problem you're seeing is caused by GlassFish scanning your application for annotations. It does this by loading all of the classes in the application and it's failing as a class that's referenced by one of the annotations isn't on the classpath. Unfortunately, there's no way in GlassFish 3 to configure what it does and does not scan for annotations. I believe that things have improved in GlassFish 4 so, if upgrading is an option, you might want to try that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in both Glassfish 3.X and Glassfish 4.X.
Maybe it is caused by Glassfish when it attempts to find out Classes that are refenced by  [Spring boot conditional annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-condition-annotations).
A simple try/catch in Glassfish code solves this problem. look at the proposition [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21265).